# Редактирование строковых ресурсов из кода android

Tags: android, java, строки

Добрый день подскажите как отредактировать строку, которая хранится в string.xml, прямо из кода. если это конечно возможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На андроид все ресурсы доступны только для чтения!

Comment: Ясно, спасибо.