# Создание строковых ресурсов во время работы приложения.Передача данных в диалог фрагмент

Tags: java, android, строки, dialogfragment

Допустим, мне надо в появившемся диалогфрагменте отображать текст (он всё время разный) . Могу указать в xml на строковый ресурс. Но смогу ли я во время работы программы изменять этот ресурс, чтобы перед отображением диалог фрагмента этот ресурс был уже изменен? Мне кажется ,что нет. Тем более сохранение ресурса займет время(сохранение на жесткий диск или пусть ssd , все же медленнее чем делать всё в оперативке) и выходит для этого дела мне стоит использовать ответ данный здесь [Как передать значение из активити в фрагмент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455014)           Неужели это самый простой способ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/256898/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, изменять ресурсы в рантайме нельзя, т.к. они упаковываются в `apk` на этапе компиляции и являются статическими.

Да, передавать данные во фрагменты через `setArgument(Bundle args)` - это правильный и простой способ.